# Part::partw: error in Custom Spline Algorithm

Tags: warning-messages, splines

I am attending a Calculus course where we use Wolfram as a supporting tool, and I was trying the algorithm provided for Spline interpolation and I get the error in the picture:
[image]

```
    (* Interpolare liniara a unei liste de valori  experimentale *)

x = {0, 1.5, 2, 3.5, 4, 5, 6, 7.3, 8, 9};
y = {6, 4, 5, 3, 6, 1, 0, -2.8, -3, -1};
n = Length[x];
lst = {};
For[i = 1, i <= n, i++, 
  AppendTo[lst, {x[[i]], y[[i]]}];
  Subscript[h, i] = x[[i + 1]] - x[[i]];
  ];
(* Graficul compus din puncte unite prin segmente *)
g1 = 
 ListPlot[lst, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, Joined -> True]
(*Interpolare spline cubic a unei liste de valori *)

A = Table[0, {n - 2}, {n}];
Y = Table[0, {n - 2}];
For[i = 1, i <= n - 2, i++,
  A[[i, i]] = Subscript[h, i];
  A[[i, i + 1]] = 2 (Subscript[h, i] + Subscript[h, i + 1]);
  A[[i, i + 2]] = Subscript[h, i + 1];
  ];

For[i = 1, i <= n - 2, i++,
  Y[[i]] = 
   3 (y[[i]]/Subscript[h, i] - y[[i + 1]]/Subscript[h, i] - 
      y[[i + 1]]/Subscript[h, i + 1] + y[[i + 2]]/Subscript[h, 
      i + 1])
  ];
AA = Table[A[[i, j]], {i, 1, n - 2}, {j, 2, n - 1}];
B = Inverse[AA].Y;
Print["A=", MatrixForm[A]]; (*Matricea sistemului*)
Print["AA=", 
 MatrixForm[AA]];  (*Matricea membrul stang *)
Print["B=", 
 MatrixForm[B]];  (*Matricea termenilor liberi*)
a = 
 d = c = Table[0, {n}];
b = Table[B[[i - 1]], {i, n}];
b[[1]] = -2;
b[[n]] = -2;
For[i = 1, i <= n - 1, i++,
  a[[i]] = (b[[i + 1]] - b[[i]] )/(3 Subscript[h, i]);
  c[[i]] = (
   3 y[[i + 1]] - 3 y[[i]] - 2 (Subscript[h, i])^2 b[[i]] - 
    Subscript[h, i]^2 b[[i + 1]])/(3 Subscript[h, i]);
  d[[i]] = y[[i]];
  ];
For[j = 1, j <= n - 1, j++, 
  
  S[j] = a[[j]] (X - x[[j]])^3 + b[[j]] (X - x[[j]])^2 + 
     c[[j]] (X - x[[j]]) + d[[j]];
  ];

f = \!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(j = 1\), \(n - 1\)]\(\*
StyleBox[
RowBox[{"S", "[", "j", "]"}],
FontSize->18] \(\*
StyleBox["(",
FontSize->18]\*
StyleBox[
RowBox[{"UnitStep", "[", 
RowBox[{"X", "-", 
RowBox[{"x", "[", 
RowBox[{"[", "j", "]"}], "]"}]}], "]"}],
FontSize->18]\*
StyleBox[" ",
FontSize->18]\*
StyleBox["-",
FontSize->18]\*
StyleBox[" ",
FontSize->18]\(\*
StyleBox["UnitStep",
FontSize->18]\)\*
StyleBox["[",
FontSize->18]\*
StyleBox["X",
FontSize->18]\*
StyleBox["-",
FontSize->18]x[\([j + 1]\)]])\)\)\);
g2 = Plot [f, {x, 0, 9}, PlotStyle -> Red];
Show[g1, g2]
```

In order for you to be more comfortable I placed here the notebook and the screenshots of this part from the course.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1WSQTv_AQurvt_zfbBp_XDj4svTt4qjt8?usp=sharing

As a side note the professor uses Mathematica 11 and I am using Mathematica 12.

Thank you in advance for your help.
What is weird is that in the video on Youtube it works.
The screenshots are from that one.
I tried also with version 11, the same he uses, and I still have this issue.
[image: Algo part 1]
[image: Algo part 2]
[image: Algo part 3]
[image: Algo part 4]

Comment: The next line with this issue seems this one:
b=Table[B[[i-1]], {i, n}];
How can I fix it?

Comment: Davide, for your recent comment: you would make it so B[[i-1]] doesn’t contain B[[0]], which does not exist as index starts at 1 in Mathematica. Meaning you want to start at i+1. Whether you then go to n+1 depends on your use-case & need for B & b. I highly recommend posting images or latex formatted text that shows the algorithm to avoid future issues with the linked content.

Comment: @CATrevillian I have a dded a few pictures with the algorithm as per your request. Thank you.

Comment: Davide, I was hoping to see something like a pseudocode version of the algorithm, in hopes that one could just determine their own approach to the implementation. There are a number of issues with the methods that the instructor appears to have been successful in using. I don’t know how the methods shown were functional, but I wish you luck in figuring this out. I hope that another who comes to this question can fix the implementation you show in your screenshots! It seems to be functional only due to the order of evaluation, and would be better if many global variables were instead made local